# json.loads(x) works offline but not online

Tags: json, python-3.8

I'm doing a download of information from a router. The received data is a string with a json-like structure.

For example, using `netmiko` I ask the router for information, and this is what I get (just doing a simple print).

```
rx = conn2rtr.send_command('info json\n')
```

The `rx` string is the following.

```
print(rx)
{
"nokia-state:version-number": "B-21.7.R2",
"nokia-state:version-string": "TiMOS-B-21.7.R2 both\/x86_64 Nokia 7750 SR Copyright (c) 2000-2021 Nokia. All rights reserved. All use subject to applicable license agreements. Built on Wed Sep 15 12:57:16 PDT 2021 by builder in \/builds\/c\/217B\/R2\/panos\/main\/sros"
}
```

I do some treatment on the string, such as...

```
rx       = rx.replace("\r", "")
rx       = rx.replace("\n", "")
rx       = rx.replace("\0", "")
rx       = f"'{rx}'"
```

And after printing again, this is what I get:

```
'{    "nokia-state:version-number": "B-21.7.R2",    "nokia-state:version-string": "TiMOS-B-21.7.R2 both\/x86_64 Nokia 7750 SR Copyright (c) 2000-2021 Nokia. All rights reserved. All use subject to applicable license agreements. Built on Wed Sep 15 12:57:16 PDT 2021 by builder in \/builds\/c\/217B\/R2\/panos\/main\/sros"}'
```

If I copy+paste that resulting string into the python shell, meaning, working offline, I can convert that into a dictionary, such as:

```
In [58]: h = '{    "nokia-state:version-number": "B-21.7.R2",    "nokia-state:version-string": "TiMOS-B-21.7.R2 both\/x86_64 Nokia 7750 SR Copyright (c) 2000-2021 Nokia. All rights reserved. All use subj
    ...: ect to applicable license agreements. Built on Wed Sep 15 12:57:16 PDT 2021 by builder in \/builds\/c\/217B\/R2\/panos\/main\/sros"}'

In [59]: json.loads(h)
Out[59]: 
{'nokia-state:version-number': 'B-21.7.R2',
 'nokia-state:version-string': 'TiMOS-B-21.7.R2 both/x86_64 Nokia 7750 SR Copyright (c) 2000-2021 Nokia. All rights reserved. All use subject to applicable license agreements. Built on Wed Sep 15 12:57:16 PDT 2021 by builder in /builds/c/217B/R2/panos/main/sros'}
```

However, if I try to do it on-the-fly, meaning doing a `json.loads(rx)` on the received data from the router, I get the error `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.

There is clearly something wrong with the string `rx` that goes away if I copy+paste that, which is bothering the `json.loads()` method.

What else can I check to solve this?

thanks.

Comment: Those singlequotes `'` are not part of JSON, are you trying to parse them?

Comment: Well, good point. If i use double-quotes around `rx` instead of single-quotes, then I do not get this error. But, again, offline I can get a python dictionary. However, online, `json.loads(rx)` return a string... let me update the question to make it clearer ...

Comment: You shouldn't put _either of them_ around the string.

Comment: @tkausl, you are right! I was messing around with this single/double quotes (because I saw it working on the python shell). But now that you mention it, y removed the line `rx       = f"'{rx}'"` and it is working as expected ... thank you !!